# How to completely remove MS SQL Server 2008 R2 x64 which was uninstalled incorrectly?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, uninstall, manual

On my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 I can't do anything with the existing instance of MS SQL Server 2008 R2. It was my mistake to uninstall some components related to SQL Server before running the main uninstaller.

Now the uninstaller seems like doing its job and reporting "All done", but in the end nothing happens, "\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" folder still has 700 Mb of content. Reboot has no effect.

How to remove SQL Server 2008 R2 manually?

Comment: Which components have you uninstalled?  Did you try reinstalling them?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but there were lots of them in an "installed software" list. I have removed all of them except the main SQL server items. So now I have only 2 related options left in my software list: "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bit version)" and "Setup software of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2"

Comment: I've managed to uninstall it with the instruction in [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [SQL Server 2008 installation fails when you try to install SQL Server a second time](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404)
- [How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955499)
- [How to manually uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967)

Answer (score -2):

Rerun the SQL Server 2008 R2 setup and use Remove option. It it does'n work I suggest tp try the Repair option and then again Remove

Answer (score -2):

To uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2 we have 2 options by using control panel or from SQL Server setup and click on remove and select all features and uninstall.